# Link to Application Tab from Profile box (Facebook app)

Tags: facebook

I would like to place a link from my application's narrow profile box to it's application tab on the same profile.

I have combed through the FBML documentation to no avail. I have posted this question on the Facebook dev forums. I have experimented with pasting the URL of the tab into the profile box link without success (ajax may be getting in the way?).

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked this a very long time ago, but it ranks well in Google for some search terms so here goes:

To link to a specific profile tab you can use the following href in your anchor

facebook.com/profile.php?id=123456&v=app_654321

obviously you need to replace the profile id and app id with correct values.

With the new short urls you may use this href

facebook.com/shorturl?v=app_654321

Both will load up the users profile with your apps tab already selected.

Comment: Awesome! I still might need this... Thanks!

Comment: Thank you.. I've been searching for this now for three days and have found it here!

Comment: in addition to this, sometimes you might need to add `target="_top"` to your anchor. That was the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not with the profile.php... It always redirects to page wall, no matter of v parameter.
The only way I know is to give a direct link, ie.

http://www.facebook.com/MichaelJordan?v=info

The problem is that you have to know this name in the link (MichaelJordan).

To go to your application's tab, you need parameter v=app_APPID